# I have '0001/16' value in my MySQL Data Base. How can i write in where clause as '1/16' to select?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, select

I have '0001/16' value in my MySQL Data Base. How can i write in where clause as '1/16'  to select ?

Note : we cannot predict how many zeros before nonzero digit.

Hibernate Criteria will be more helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql you could do this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SET @T = '001/16';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select @T
    -> FROM DUAL
    -> WHERE
    -> concat(
    -> REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@T,1,INSTR(@T,'/') - 1),'0','')
    -> ,
    -> substring(@t,INSTR(@T,'/'),length(@t) - 1)
    -> )
    -> = '1/16'
    -> ;
+--------+
| @T     |
+--------+
| 001/16 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```